# Using Angular's routes collection for populating a navigation area

Tags: angular, routes

When developing apps in Angular 2 I find myself having redundant code in my app when it comes to routes. Once I have my routes exported from a file for RouterModule use, I would imagine it to become a single source of truth - re-used for populating navigation areas in the app.

The problem is, that the [Route interface](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0-beta.2/modules/%40angular/router/src/config.ts#L12-L253) item does not allow any kind of 'label' attribute. If it did, I could iterate over the array, pick up a specified level (root or children or any route) and if the path was not `''` or `**` I would return the item and use its `label`.

Now, as wishful as it sounds, I just wanted to describe the problem. Has anyone come up to a sneaky solution for that purpose?

*For a moment I thought of cloning the routes collection and applying my own labels on top of each item, but it would again produce some unnecessary code on another end*

Comment: Is it not possble to use data attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes in an Angular application are just an array of objects. In other words, they're a JavaScript variable. How you obtain this variable is up to you.

You could have an `allRoutes` variable acting as the single source of truth:

```ts
// Note that I haven't used the `Routes` type.
// You could define your own interface for this.
const allRoutes: any[] = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, label: 'Home' },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent, label: 'Contact' },
  // ...
};
```

Then, use that to generate router-compatible routes:

```ts
// Iterate over `allRoutes` to produce the following.
// The `label` property is gone.
const routerFriendlyRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  // ...
};
```